# How to use ConnectApi.ChatterFeeds class if Chatter is disabled

Tags: apex, chatter, connect-api

I have the following problem: my code uses **ConnectApi.ChatterFeeds.postFeedElement** and **ConnectApi.ChatterFeeds.postFeedElementBatch** methods to operate feed items. That works properly is Chatter is enabled for the org, but ... if it's disabled I can't even install my package because of **Invalid class ChatterFeeds** exception coming from my unit tests. I realize that some Chatter object aren't accessible when Chatter is disabled (for example **FeedItem**), but you can always write

```
SObjectType token = Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get('FeedItem');
SObject objPost = token.newSObject();
```

instead of

```
FeedItem f = new FeedItem();
```

Does anyone know if there is a workaround like that for **ChatterFeeds** class methods? Or I have to get rid of **ConnectApi** and rewrite my Chatter logic somehow else?

**UPDATE (Sep 29 2015)**

Salesforce team just confirmed it is a known behavior: ConnectApi expects Chatter to be enabled and that's a runtime check which can't be avoided.

**UPDATE (Nov 10 2015)**

Fixed by Salesforce in Winter'16 Patch 11.0 (already deployed to the most org).
Details are [here](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p30000000eNXCAA2)

Answer (score 1):

You can use Connect API to detect the features your org is enabled

```
if(ConnectApi.Organization.getSettings().features.chatter) {
     //Logic here
 }
```

Reference links

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_connectapi_output_features.htm

Comment: That won't help because it's a compilation problem, not a runtime. This class is not supported when Chatter is disabled.

Comment: Other would be add try and catch around this and handle the catch ?Try and catch will work on all scenarios

Comment: Again, seems like that is a compilation error, so try catch doesn't help.